# How to get string that contain between/match/exist arrays in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get any strings that match between these two arrays but unfortunately not successful.

```
arr1 = ['crepas','aevig','rolex']
arr2 = ['fs', ':', 'rolex', 'datejust', '41', '126300', 'silver', 'dial', 'jubilee', '-', '2018', 'warranty', 'fs', ':', 'rolex', 'datejust', '41', '126300', 'silver', 'dial', 'jubilee', '-', '2018', 'warranty']

res = [arr1.index(i) for i in arr2] 
print(res)
```

I got this error message

```
ValueError: 'fs' is not in list
```

Should be like this

```
rolex
```

Comment: does it need to return only one time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to check if an element in `arr1` is also `in arr2`, try this instead:

```
res = [x for x in arr1 if x in arr2]
```

Using `index()` here isn't a good idea because:

1. It returns the *index* of the element not the element itself
2. It'll throw an exception if the element is not present

Also notice that the filtering condition for a list comprehension should go in the rightmost part of it. If you don't care about preserving the order of the elements, using a `set` will probably be more efficient, as pointed by other answers:

```
res = set(arr1).intersection(arr2)
```

Comment: List Comprehension is probably the best way here.... Filter could also be used but is less readable IMHO - filter( lambda x: True if x in arr2 else False , arr1)

Comment: If you want only unique elements in res with order preserved you can use dict comprehension. `res={i:None for i in arr2 if i in arr1}; output=res.keys()`.

Comment: @Tooblippe, `set` is faster and probably the best way, which is using internal implementation in C.

Comment: @Ch3steR why a dict, when a set would do better?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez  but set is an unordered collection. I was saying if OP needs order to be preserved and want only unique values then `dict` is better. As `dict` preserves the order in which keys are added.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez The question is unclear if OP wants only uniques values or order to be preserved. If OP wants only unique values with order preserved `dict` is helpful. As `dict`preserves the order in which keys are added.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a set here as you need to output a single value for multiple occurances:

```
res = set(arr1).intersection(arr2)
```

Note with internal implementation in C, this would be faster.

Comment: `set` is fastest to eliminate duplicates. But set is an unordered collection. If OP needs order to be preserved and wants only unique values then `dict` is better. As `dict` preserves the order in which keys are added.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
arr3=list(set(arr1).intersection(set(arr2)))

print(arr3)
```

Returns:

```py
['rolex']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to go with list comprehension you can use `sets` for it like this:

```py
arr1 = ['crepas','aevig','rolex']
arr2 = ['fs', ':', 'rolex', 'datejust', '41', '126300', 'silver', 'dial', 'jubilee', '-', '2018', 'warranty', 'fs', ':', 'rolex', 'datejust', '41', '126300', 'silver', 'dial', 'jubilee', '-', '2018', 'warranty']

res = set(arr1).intersection(set(arr2))
print(res)


>>> {'rolex'}
```